# Security problems with autologin and FormsAuthenticationTicket

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, cookies, authentication

Im using autologin on my MVC 3 website.

How do I best handle this problem:

A user signs in at his own computer (and gets a 30 day cookie)

Same user signs in at a friends computer (and gets a 30 day cookie)

Its now possible to autologin in at both computers. The user realizes this and changes his password but his friend is still able to autologin from his computer until the cookie expires.

How do I best handle this?

I could of course set at date on the user when password changed and check this up against the date in the cookie.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: what do you mean by "autologin"?

Comment: @RPM1984: bypassing the authentication process using login cookie set from remember me checkbox

Comment: isn't that stock standard asp.net forms auth, with a persistent cookie? just never heard it named "autologin" i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what you're saying, but I think you're implying an association between the "remember me" function and the "password change" function which in practice, isn't there. The auth token you get when authenticating is not generally tied to the value of the password (i.e. when using the membership provider), after all, you're logically keeping the *identity* authenticated across sessions and in this regard, it works just fine.

To be honest, this sounds like more of a user behaviour problem than a technology problem. In your use case, someone is consciously asking the browser to allow them to remain authenticated for a long period of time and doing so on a machine which they have no control over. Of course I'm assuming you have a "remember me" checkbox and if you don't, there's your answer right there.

The other thing you might want to look at is what OWASP talks about in part 3 of the Top 10 - [Broken authentication and session management](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/07/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-3.html). This link will put it in a .NET context for you but in short, it talks a lot about reducing the opportunity for exactly what you're describing to happen by things like eager session expiration, disabling sliding sessions and obviously giving end users the control to expire the token at session expiration and log out at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't yo have Remember me checkbox on your login form. The value of this checkbox will dictate whether you are going to create persistent cookie or not. if you don't create persistent cookie, it will expire as soon as session ends. In this scenario you user can leave Remember me checkbox unchecked when logging in on his friends computer. If he doesn't he is calling for trouble himself.

Comment: Good point. But it's still a problem if a ticket based on an old password still can login after password change.

Comment: you can create authentication ticket with combination of username and password as key since ticket is encrypted before setting cookies value there are no chances of exposing sensitive information